# What is your father like?

Tags: expressions

Does question ''What is your father like'' imply information solely about personality properties of the the father in question; or else does it imply as well physical properties of outer appearance in addition to those of personality?

Comment: It means anything it could possibly mean, with no more context - anything at all that your father could be like.

Answer (score 0):

When used for a person, the idiomatic expression ***[what is he, are they, etc. like?](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/what-is-he-are-they-etc-like)***  refers to the personal aspects  (character,  personality etc.)
​

> - said to ask someone to describe someone or something to you:
>
>   - *What was her boyfriend like?
>       "What was the weather like?" "It rained all week."
>       You've seen their new house, haven't you? What's it like?*

Cambridge Dictionary

- To ask about the physical appearance you would say: "***What does your father [look like](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/look+like)?"***

Comment: The ''look like'' expression is aithout any ambiguity.  What I wonder is when  asked about someone in expression eg '' What is your girl friend like'' wouldn't the person directing the question be interested in both character and appearnce properties of the ''girl'' ? Is the question necessarily exluding the appearance implication; or else there could be an implication of appearance as well besides personality?